# Run systemd service after automount but after it's accessed

Tags: mount, systemd

Is it possible to run a systemd service that prepares an automounted file system for use? This service would need to run after the filesystem is mounted, but before whatever triggered the automount accesses it.

For example, I want to always ensure certain directories exist on a file system when mounting it. Theses directories might be deleted between mounts, so they must be made each time the file system is mounted. The catch is that whatever process triggered the automount might expect those directories to be there and so the directories would need to be created before the process (or any other processes) are allowed to access it.

I can come up with some kludges to accomplish this like mounting the filesystem somewhere else, preparing it, and then remounting it in the correct location, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Untested by me, but you may be able to adapt this approach using a mixture of `/etc/fstab` along with systemd: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Fstab_-_Use_SystemD_automount.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198123/ for a question about doing similar at unmount time.