# Automatically run command before umounting a filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, systemd, unmounting

I want to execute a command automatically shortly before a filesystem is unmounted. The command still needs the filesystem to be mounted but I am interested in information as "new" as possible. Therefore a simple cron job is not a nice solution. (You can assume the command is `df /the/mount/point`.)

Is there any way to run a command automatically just before a filesystem is unmounted? Via a mount option or systemd or anything else?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196732/ for a question about doing similar at mount time.

Answer (score 1):

rename /bin/umount to /bin/umount.real

Write a script which runs the commands you want to call before unmounting and then call /bin/umount.real

create a soft link to your script as /bin/umount

Comment: Is there any guaranty that every program that will unmount a filesystem uses `/bin/unmount`? Or might some programs (like systemd for example) use a `umount` system call internally?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee. if an app has been programmed to call umount(), then this method will fail.